# How to style message and icon in Dynamic Dialog Angular PrimeNG in only one component?

Tags: css, angular, typescript, primeng

I am trying to style the **message** and **icon** properties **only one** dialog in this .ts file and when I use provided .scss code, I am styling **all** dialogs in the whole app that I **do not** want to. I think I am doing something wrong with **ng-deep** or **host** selectors?

.ts:

```
  onDelete(uuid: string): void {
    this.confirmationService.confirm({
      message: this.translateService.instant(
        'DELETE_MESSAGE',
      ),
      header: this.translateService.instant('CONFIRM'),
      icon: 'pi pi-exclamation-triangle',
      accept: () => {
        this.myServide.deleteSomething(uuid).subscribe(() => {
          this.messageService.add({
            severity: ToastSeverity.SUCCESS,
            summary: 'SUCCESS',
            detail: 'DELETED_MESSAGE',
            life: 3000,
          });
          this.getData();
        });
        this.confirmationService.close();
      },
      reject: () => {
        this.confirmationService.close();
      },
    });
  }
```

.scss:

```
:host ::ng-deep {
      .formFooter > div:nth-child(1) {
        right: 30px !important;
        height: 100px !important;
      }
    }


::ng-deep .p-dialog.p-confirm-dialog .p-confirm-dialog-message {
  color: #eb3b5a;
}

::ng-deep .pi-exclamation-triangle:before {
  color: #eb3b5a;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

To display the dialog, in your `HTML` code you must have something like this:
`<p-confirmPopup></p-confirmPopup>`

Try to use a custom class there:
`<p-confirmPopup styleClass="custom-class"></p-confirmPopup>`

Now use CSS as below:

```
::ng-deep .custom-class.p-dialog.p-confirm-dialog .p-confirm-dialog-message {
  color: #eb3b5a;
}
```